# how to compare listbox values and table values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my scenario just select the list box options, that values and text going to append to the table rows, but im facing small issues, user not allow to select same options (already selected options) and user not allow to append same values in the table.. if user select same option show alert messages like, 'you are already selected, select another option' like that..

here is my sample code fiddle..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/719jhtfc/)

Sample snippet here..

```js
$("#excist_supp").on("change", function() {
  $(".indexDrop").hide();

  var newText = $("#excist_supp option:selected").text();
  var newValue = $("#excist_supp option:selected").val();

  $("#letterTable tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" id="sm_supp" value="' + newText + '" class="form-control newStyle1" name="sm_supp" readonly></td><td><input type="text" id="sm_code" value="' + newValue + '" class="form-control newStyle2" name="sm_code" readonly></td><td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel newExcist" style="width:30%;position: relative;right: 25%; margin-bottom:0px">x</button></a></td></tr>');




  $("#letterTable tr").each(function(i) {

    var count = (i) - 1;
    if (i === 0) return;
    var input1 = $(this).find('.newStyle1');
    var input2 = $(this).find('.newStyle2');

    // id
    input1.eq(0).attr("id", "sm_supp" + count); // Text fields
    input2.eq(0).attr("id", "sm_code" + count);

    // name
    input1.eq(0).attr("name", "sm_supp[" + count + "]"); // Text fields
    input2.eq(0).attr("name", "sm_code[" + count + "]");
  });

});

/* compare two fields */

$('#excist_supp').change(function() {
  $("#letterTable tr").each(function(i) {

    var listVal = $('#excist_supp').val();
    var tableVal = $('.newStyle2').val();
    var nawTab = JSON.stringify(tableVal);

    if (listVal == nawTab) {
      alert('Matching!');
      return true;
    } else {
      alert('Not matching!');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <!-- Existing Suppliers -->

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <input class="form-control serch" id="supSearch" type="search" placeholder="Search Existing Suppliers..">
          <div class="selector">
            <select class="col-12 listbox newBox" name="List_0" size="20" id="excist_supp" style="height: 125px !important;">
              <option class="indexDrop">Choose Existing Suppliers</option>
              <option value="0000">Komal </option>
              <option value="0001">Ranjeet</option>
              <option value="0002">Vishal </option>
              <option value="0003">Gaurav</option>
              <option value="0004">Dhanpat</option>
              <option value="0005">Joe</option>
              <option value="0006">Gowri</option>
              <option value="0007">shankar</option>
              <option value="0008">Dhanpat</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Table -->

  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
          <div class="table-scroll">
            <table id="letterTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped order-scroll order-list" style="width: 95%;">
              <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #680f79;color: #fff;">
                  <th class="text-center">Supplier Name</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Supplier Code</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="mytbody" style="text-align: center;">

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `$("#excist_supp").on("change"....` and `$('#excist_supp').change(function()...` you are attaching the same event to the same element twice.

You can create a temporary array of all the used list values and create a function to check if the current value is exist in that array or not using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Try the following way:

```js
$("#excist_supp").on("change", function() {

  if(!checkValue()){
    $(".indexDrop").hide();
    var newText = $("#excist_supp option:selected").text();
    var newValue = $("#excist_supp option:selected").val();

    $("#letterTable tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" id="sm_supp" value="' + newText + '" class="form-control newStyle1" name="sm_supp" readonly></td><td><input type="text" id="sm_code" value="' + newValue + '" class="form-control newStyle2" name="sm_code" readonly></td><td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel newExcist" style="width:30%;position: relative;right: 25%; margin-bottom:0px">x</button></a></td></tr>');

    $("#letterTable tr").each(function(i) {

      var count = (i) - 1;
      if (i === 0) return;
      var input1 = $(this).find('.newStyle1');
      var input2 = $(this).find('.newStyle2');

      // id
      input1.eq(0).attr("id", "sm_supp" + count); // Text fields
      input2.eq(0).attr("id", "sm_code" + count);

      // name
      input1.eq(0).attr("name", "sm_supp[" + count + "]"); // Text fields
      input2.eq(0).attr("name", "sm_code[" + count + "]");
    });
  }

});

/* compare two fields */
var temp = [];
function checkValue() {
  var listVal = $('#excist_supp').val();
  var tableVal = $('.newStyle2').val();
  var nawTab = JSON.stringify(tableVal);
  if (temp.includes(listVal)) {
    alert('Matching!');
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Not matching!');
    temp.push(listVal)
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <!-- Existing Suppliers -->

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <input class="form-control serch" id="supSearch" type="search" placeholder="Search Existing Suppliers..">
          <div class="selector">
            <select class="col-12 listbox newBox" name="List_0" size="20" id="excist_supp" style="height: 125px !important;">
              <option class="indexDrop">Choose Existing Suppliers</option>
              <option value="0000">Komal </option>
              <option value="0001">Ranjeet</option>
              <option value="0002">Vishal </option>
              <option value="0003">Gaurav</option>
              <option value="0004">Dhanpat</option>
              <option value="0005">Joe</option>
              <option value="0006">Gowri</option>
              <option value="0007">shankar</option>
              <option value="0008">Dhanpat</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Table -->

  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
          <div class="table-scroll">
            <table id="letterTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped order-scroll order-list" style="width: 95%;">
              <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #680f79;color: #fff;">
                  <th class="text-center">Supplier Name</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Supplier Code</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="mytbody" style="text-align: center;">

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much bro! and can you tell me the use of "temp.includes"

Comment: @Joe, *The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate*...more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: how to compare after removing row.. now my issue is i just add row and click delete button, row will deleted and again i select that same options, its said its matching.. why?